# Can't view or edit stored procedures in Netbeans (PostgreSQL connection)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, netbeans, jdbc, plpgsql

I just installed Netbeans (7.0 IDE Dev) on my mac, and I am quite happy that i dont need 2 editors anymore (1 for php, 1 for python)

Now, I got even more enthousiastic when i saw that i could connect to my PostgreSQL server, this came in super-handy for editing my stored procedures (instead of copying/pasting the functions from the phppgadmin to my editor).

Logging in to PostgreSQL went fine, as admin, i can view the tables, views and stored procedures, i can even edit tables, execute sql etc.

Unfortunately, i cant see the contents of the stored procedures, or edit them.

I tried different JDBC versions, but that didnt change something. (the options edit, view are grayed out)

I hope someone had the same problem or knows what i am doing wrong...

Any help is REALLY welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think viewing/editing stored procedures is not supported for PostgreSQL in NetBeans